# Creating buttons in java

Tags: java, android, button

I'm pretty new to learning about java and android development; so please help me out. In the next line of code I am trying to create a button but I am having trouble understanding why the 'id' is underlined. When I fix it in the R folder the .blue_yes gets underlined and I am confused what I should do next? Any help would be helpful. 
Thanks

```
    Button yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue_yes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBtAdapter.enable();
            setResult(CheckBluetoothEnabledActivity.RESULT_SUCCESS);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue_cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(CheckBluetoothEnabledActivity.RESULT_CANCEL);
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean underlined? Are you seeing any red marks in eclipse?

Comment: yeah, there is a red underline under 'id'. It is saying that the id is not resolved or it is not a field. If that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a button in the layout xml file with id blue_yes and blue_cancel before accessing that control in your in your code. probably you have not declared the control in your xml file correctly.

Once you specify a control in Layout file entry in R.Java is automatically made by eclipse android plugin. you don't need to mess with R folder and its file as R.java in automatically generated file and you should not change anything in that.

if even after declaring your control in layout file you are not able to get your control using findViewById method then please post your layout file as well to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data, one of gazillion possible explanations is that you don't have R imported (and then fix it by creating a new class, and the new class lacks the id attribute).